# Did malloc succeed or fail?

Tags: c, macos, malloc

The following program:

```
/* gcc -O1 -g3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -m32 t.c -o t.exe */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    static const unsigned int MALLOC_SIZE = 0x80000000;
    int ret = -1;

    unsigned char * ptr = malloc(MALLOC_SIZE);
    if(ptr) {
        printf("Allocation succeeded\n");
        printf("%02X … %02X\n", ptr[0], ptr[MALLOC_SIZE - 1]);
        free(ptr);
        ret = 0;
    } else {
        printf("Allocation succeeded\n");
        ret = 1;
    }
    return ret;
}

$ lipo -info t.exe
Non-fat file: t.exe is architecture: i386
```

Produces the following output:

```
$ ./t.exe
t.exe(19449) malloc: *** mmap(size=2147483648) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Allocation succeeded
```

If the allocation failed, why did I get back a non-null pointer?

Comment: Hmm.. You are printing "Allocation succeeded" in either case.

Comment: Dooh...................

Comment: You should answer the question so I can give you the points.

Comment: seems like  the `else` it's the one executing the code. sure it's not a NULL pointer? :) LOL

Comment: Thanks Kira. It sucks getting old.

Comment: -_- it sucks I know. XD

Comment: Where did the message `t.exe(19449) malloc: *** mmap(size=2147483648) failed (error code=12)` come from? `malloc` is not allowed to print messages on failure...or is this coming from some debugging tool you were running your program under?

Comment: Thanks R. I suppose that came from Mac OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing "allocation succeded" in either case, which could be a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. SO would not let me accept the answer immediately. Apparently there's a 10 or 15 minute waiting period.